# Webpack - sockjs.js SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 1 (occured on Chrome only)

Tags: javascript, webpack

this issue bothered me for whole week, as I running webpack-dev-server and make changes on "src/.html|*.js|.css" files.
And the error appeared only on Chrome.

[Chrome Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhNZm.jpg)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd3gT.png)

I have tried delete "node_modules", clear npm cache and npm install, still no luck.
Also, I tried to build other (different) tutorial projects, the problem still persists once after I made changes while running "webpack-dev-server".

I tried my luck on Google, but doesn't seems any luck from it.

Thanks in advance.